# Script run under Jenkins fails due to mis-recognized tokens

Tags: bash, shell-script, jenkins

I'm creating a build job within the Jenkins CI/CD software. The build job will clone my android project from Github and generates the APK. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server OS.

As part of the build step, I'm executing the following command via Jenkins:

```
rm -r app/src/main/java/in/myproj/utils/Constants.kt
```

But receiving the following error:

```
/tmp/jenkins10737829520192897047.sh: 1: Syntax error: "in" unexpected
```

It looks like the bash is treating the folder name `in` as a `Constant`. I have been trying to find a solution since morning today but failed miserably. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I have debugged the issue further and found the actual cause. It is not the `rm` command that is failing. I have another build step where I'm appending some code snippets to a file. The following is the code snippet that is actually failing:

```
cat << EOT >> app/src/main/java/in/myproj/utils/Constants.kt

"package `in`.myproj.utils

class Constants {
    companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://api.example.in/api/"
        const val BASE_URL_IMAGE_ADDRESS = "https://dashboard.example.in:5555/"
        const val BASE_URL_PROFILE_IMAGE_ADDRESS = "https://api.example.in/"
        const val ABOUT_US_URL = "https://example.in/aboutus.html"
        const val PRIVACY_POLICY_URL = "https://example.in/privacy-policy.html"
        const val TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_URL = "https://example.in/terms-condition.html"
        const val REQUEST_TIMEOUT_DURATION = 10
        const val STATUS_SUCCESS = 1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some context. Is that the _entire_ script? How do you run the script? What operating system are you using?

Comment: @terdon Thanks. I have updated my question.

Comment: Thanks. But i) is that the _entire_ script and ii) how do you run it exactly? The error doesn't make sense. My first guess is that there is some non-printing character there. Can you also add the output of `cat -v your_script.sh`?

Comment: @terdon `rm -r app/src/main/java/in/myproj/utils/Constants.kt` is the entire script. When I execute it via terminal directly, it works fine. It fails only when I execute it via Jenkins.

Comment: Can you also add the output of `cat -v /tmp/jenkins10737829520192897047.sh`? And how does Jenkins execute it? Does it help if you add a shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) to the top of your script?

Comment: I have already tried with the `shebang` and quoting the command. Jenkins adds the `rm -r app/src/main/java/in/myproj/utils/Constants.kt` command to the `/tmp/jenkins10737829520192897047.sh` file and executes it. This file automatically gets deleted after executing the job.

Comment: Can you please (and this is the third time I have asked) post the output of `cat -v /tmp/jenkins10737829520192897047.sh`? There is nothing special about `in`, this shouldn't be happening so I am guessing there is a non-printing character there somewhere. Or, even more likely, there is some other line in that script causing the error.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your comment and apologies for not sharing the output. As I mentioned earlier, I do not have an option to `cat` the output of the bash script since it gets auto-deleted as soon as the Jenkins finishes the execution. But, I have made some progress and found the actual reason for the failure. I have updated my question. Thank you once again for your patience.

Comment: Ah-ha! Now that makes more sense. I know what's wrong now :). Are there any shell variables further down in your heredoc (the bit between `cat << EOT` and the closing `EOT`)? If yes, please update your question to reflect that. If not, my answer should be what you need. By the way, for your next debugging session, simply add `cat $0 > /tmp/foo.sh` to the start of your script to get the actual contents of the script being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you are using the EOT. When using an *unquoted* word as a heredoc delimiter, the contents of the heredoc will be expanded by the shell before being written. As explained in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

> If any part of word is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

As a result, the `` `in` `` in your heredoc is being read by the shell as a command substitution, so it tries to run the command `in` and return its output.

In practical terms, this means you need to quote the `EOT`:

```
cat << 'EOT' >> app/src/main/java/in/myproj/utils/Constants.kt
```

Note that this means that any variables you may have in your here doc will also not be expanded, but since I don't see any in your question, I am assuming that isn't a problem.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response and thank you very much for guiding me. Yes, I did not wanted to expand any of the variables and just wanted to populated the file as-is. I have implemented your suggestion and it produced the expected result. Thanks a lot!!